# Writing custom source in flume-ng

Tags: flume

I want to write my own custom source to handle application specific logs(e.g. stack traces )

So, What are the prerequisites for writing custom source. 
From Where should I start ?

I am doing it for the first time

Any reference for doing this ?

Answer (score 1):

The [Flume User Guide](http://flume.apache.org/FlumeUserGuide.html) is your starter reference. Then I suggest you take a look at some of the [other sources](https://git-wip-us.apache.org/repos/asf?p=flume.git;a=tree;f=flume-ng-core/src/main/java/org/apache/flume/source;h=8fd2a6179829c89fad391b3d3b5e9f99c550bb7e;hb=trunk) already provided by Flume. They're fairly straight forward.

Comment: hi
i want to write custom source where i can see reference code for inbuilt sources available in flume-ng

Comment: Updated my answer to include the link.

Comment: I also working on Custom Source in Flume. Please explain structure to write custom source and how we can integrate Flume with Cassandra.